# How to integrate imagekit with S3

Tags: django, django-admin, amazon-s3, boto, django-imagekit

I would like to upload from django admin app photos to S3 and associate them with my model. I have found imagekit very appropriate for this.
How can I configure imegekit to upload photos to S3 server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [django-athumb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-athumb/), this will do exactly you want.

Features:

- Primary advantage of django-athumb is, thumbnails are generated at the time of user uploading the original image. Instead of generating thumbs on-demand and making the user wait, we get that out of the way from the beginning.
- Written on sorl-thumbnail's code
- Simple and easy to install
- This may be ran on your own hardware with decent speed. Running it on EC2 makes it just that much faster.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using ImageKit 2 (alpha) - with S3 just fine.

Using `django-storages` http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

in my settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   ...,
   'storages',
   ...
)

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

# stops IK checking S3 all the time - main reason to use IK v2 for me
IMAGEKIT_DEFAULT_IMAGE_CACHE_BACKEND = 'imagekit.imagecache.NonValidatingImageCacheBackend'
```